# R xlim, ylim, zlim axis limits not working in scatterplot3d

Tags: r, plot

I'm trying to make a scatter plot with manually defined axis limits - sometimes it works, and sometimes it doesn't... I'm sure it's something simple but somehow I've not been able to find a solution.

I've put together a MWE:

```
library('scatterplot3d')
rx <- c(0,100, -80)
ry <- c(24.6,-19,14)
rz <- c(-2.1,3,-10)
axlim <- 120
spo <- scatterplot3d(rx, y=ry, z=rz, xlim = c(-axlim, axlim), ylim = c(-axlim, axlim), zlim = c(-axlim, axlim))
```

which gives me the following plot: cube with limits of +-150

[image: cube with limits of +-150]

The limits on this figure are different from the axis limits of +-120 that I've defined. Why is this?

Comment: from the documentation `Note that setting enlarged limits may not work as exactly as expected (a known but unfixed bug)`

Comment: Ok, my example was unfortunate in that respect. It also happens when I use smaller limits, e.g. using a limit of 50 produces a cube with max limit of 60

Comment: For clarity, my data set has 1000 points and the limits that I'm trying to add fall within the extremes of these points in every dimension so none of the limits are being enlarged